# tox does not run sphinx

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx, setuptools, setup.py, tox

I want to run the following command from tox.

```
python setup.py build_sphinx -b html
```

I have configured my setup.py to build the docs when I run the above command from the console (I checked that from the console, that command makes doc).

Then I have edited my tox.ini as follows:

```
.....
[testenv:sphinx]
command = python setup.py build_sphinx -b html
```

setup.cfg as follows:

```
[build_sphinx]
project = project_name
source-dir = module_name/doc
build-dir = module_name/doc/build
```

But when I run `tox -e sphinx`, tox exits with a successful message, but no docs generated.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: tox generates a directory `.tox` at the root of your project. Inside it you should find the built environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd not recommend using setuptools to build documentation. Consider instead using sphinx directly as tox itself does at https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/blob/master/tox.ini#L48-L53 Alternatively please post the exact output of the run with -vvv, or make the project publicly available for us to try it too.